# Page stretching on...and on...and on

Tags: html, frontend, web-frontend

Amazingly, the title basically explains it. We have a page that our client made which we are in the process of recreating.

The pages height just keeps going until (I am assuming this) the browser hits it's limit. I have tried firebug and W3 validator and they have both not helped.

Could this be down to unclosed tags? Or maybe the fact that this generator that she has used has stuck ID's on script tags, **THE HORROR!**.

*Any* suggestions would be great, I need to try everything here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your page source at line 193 there's this:

```
<div id="txt_2179" style="position:absolute; left:13150228px; top:1239624px; width:-832166px; height:-1239624px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;"> 
  <p class="Body-P"><span class="Body-C">LINKS</span></p> 
</div>
```

Don't know what's setting that style to that position, but this is what's causing the problem.  If you look in the very bottom right of your page you'll see `LINKS`

Is there any reason for this div to exist?  You could just remove it or remove the absolute position elements of the style.

Comment: Yep, thats the one. The developers of this tool should be...well, you get the picture. It is the single worst line of HTML I have EVER seen. Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh and yes, I will be removing it, I have no idea why this thing she used put it there, but it will have to live without it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 1.31502e+7px; top: 1239620px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden;" id="txt_2179">
<p class="Body-P"><span class="Body-C">LINKS</span></p>
</div>
```

This. Is insane!!
Is just like the whole rest of the Position Absolute's that are throughout the html.

Even when there's overflow hidden, the declaration says: top 1 million 239 thousand 620 pixels HEIGHT and the declaration for Left is as obscure as a Medieval Manuscript.

If you delete that sentence the html fits in the body. Hope you fix the rest of crazy declarations as well.

Comment: Well I didn't see the answer from ChrisKent... I was swimming through the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. Maybe it's the `3` after the `</html>` tag (well, probably not). Try fixing the errors reported by the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gardenbeet.com%2Fhanging-chair.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).